# Does changing eth0 settings in a vm virtualbox affects the host?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm reading a Linux book. I'm on a part about the 'ifconfig' command and how to change ip address, mask and mac address. There are examples in the book running the commands. I'm using a virtual machine to do tests.

If I change the eth0 settings using the ifconfig command in the vm, it will affect the host system? I'm asking this because I only have one nic card, so the vm and the host have the same hardware.

Comment: No. The things you do in the VM should be isolated to the VM.  Your question about having the same hardware depends on the NIC configuration in the VM settings.  Read about NAT vs Bridged.  Either way, the VM is isolated from the host system.  These aren't Linux things.. they are networking things.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I always create VMs using NAT (like in this case), but now I'm gonna read abount NAT vs Bridged. I was afraid of changing the settings in the VM was going to break something in the host. Thanks for answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was answered by [Señor CMasMas](https://superuser.com/users/1000631/se%C3%B1or-cmasmas):

No. The things you do in the VM should be isolated to the VM. Your question about having the same hardware depends on the NIC configuration in the VM settings. Read about NAT vs Bridged. Either way, the VM is isolated from the host system. These aren't Linux things.. they are networking things.

Comment: Since, this is not an answer, please avoid writing it as one. You can use comment function for to update your status.

Comment: Take my comment and post it as your own answer if it helped you.  Wait a couple of days and mark it as accepted if it is still the best.  Someone else *might* come along and actually write up a better one before then. :)